Kids tv show late approximately 1989 - 1992
I am trying to find a colour TV show or film I watched when I was a child in England.  I can't remember the exact year, I'd say around 1989 / 1992 ish. It was not a cartoon or animation, it was played by actors.
The only things I can remember are: a boy around 10 years old, props his bottom bed leg up with some books, the books must fall, as the boy goes to the end of the bed under the covers to replace the books. But as the boy goes further down the bed he finds stones. 
The boy gets a torch and proceeds to go further down the bed, under the covers. He ends up in a cave or tunnel and is greeted by a man I think who opens doors to another world?? 
The TV channels back then were BBC, ITV and Channel 4. 
I suspect that this was a TV show on at around 3pm-4pm. Although I cannot find anything so could be a film. 

What about a rough year? We don't know when you were a child.

Can't say any better than late 80's early 90's I'm afraid.

This might be a leap, but is it Time Bandits from 1981? It's about a boy who falls in with thieves who travel through time to steal treasures. They possess a stolen map of the universe.

Here is the trailer, but it's pretty tongue-in-cheek. Here is a scene. It's brief and out-of-context, but it's at least a bit more cohesive than the trailer. (Don't get me wrong. I love the trailer.)

I don't think so, but I'm going to watch it after this trailer! Many thanks

No, not this, but thanks for trying

I know this isn't the answer, but if you like sliding down a thing into another world, I recommend the movie Being John Malkovich.

Your description made me immediately think of Little Monsters from 1989. I remember watching it with my parents and had to look for the exact name:



While looking for the name I also found The Gate from 1987, which has a similar promise, but I'm just mentioning it here in the unlikely case it's the right one:




No, not these. But thank you for trying.
